# ifup -a only working if connected to the internet

Tags: 12.04, networking

#### Background

I have a gateway server that has been happily running 12.04 for over eighteen months. It has two interfaces, `eth3` and `wlan3`.

#### Suddenly...

`eth3` has stopped coming up on boot. Boot messages report:

```
Waiting for network configuration
Waiting for up to 60 more seconds for network configuration
```

After boot `ifconfig` shows the `lo` and `wlan3` interfaces.

```
sudo ifup -a
```

gives:

```
lo: Failed to bring up lo
eth3: Failed to bring up eth3
```

If I manually set the address with `sudo ifconfig eth3 192.168.10.201` then the interface comes up correctly.

#### But wait! There's weirdness!

In trying to reproduce the issue for this question I tried `sudo ifdown -a` then `sudo ifup -a` again. It reported my IP address (`121.45.nnn.nn`, not `192.168.10.201`) 3 times. If I turn my modem off and repeat `sudo ifdown -a` then `sudo ifup -a` again it gives:

```
Failed to bring up lo.
Failed to bring up eth3.
```

**Why does ifup -a require an internet connection to bring up a static local address?**

Here's `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # The primary network interface
    auto eth3
    iface eth3 inet static
            address 192.168.10.201
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

<sub>**Other info to avoid the xy problem**

`wlan3` is also periodically losing and unable to regain connection. I've cleaned the internals and reseated cards. Motherboard is reporting 3VDD = 3.3V so I'm ruling out a hardware issue for now.

The issue didn't appear immediately after any update. I've tried rolling back the kernel and the behaviour was the same.

This is a server install of 12.04 running `lxde`. `wicd` is used to control `wlan3`. `network-manager` is not installed.

The interfaces are named `eth3` and `wlan3` due to a convoluted install process involving a USB drive. There are no other interfaces.</sub>